# React-Leaflet How to show tooltips above layer when using panes

Tags: leaflet, react-leaflet

When using panes, the tooltip of the rectangle is shown **behind** the rectangle. How to fix this, so the tooltip is again above the layer as expected?

I tried to pass the pane argument to the Tooltip and also to set a higher zIndex on the tooltip, but none of this worked.

```
import React from "react";
import { MapContainer, Pane, Tooltip, Rectangle, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'

function Map(props) {

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[48, 11]}
      zoom={8}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Pane name="rectanglePane" style={{ zIndex: 401 }}>
        <Rectangle bounds={[[47.5, 10.5], [48.5, 11.5]]} >
          <Tooltip sticky>Rectangle Tooltip</Tooltip>
        </Rectangle>
      </Pane>
    </MapContainer>
  )
}
```

Using react-leaflet: 3.1.0

[image: Wrong behaviour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the tooltip in its own pane with a higher z index:

```js
const Map = (props) => {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={[48, 11]} zoom={8} id="mapId">
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Pane name="rectanglePane" style={{ zIndex: 401 }}>
        <Rectangle
          bounds={[
            [47.5, 10.5],
            [48.5, 11.5]
          ]}
        >
          <Pane name="ttPane" style={{ zIndex: 402 }}>
            <Tooltip sticky>Rectangle Tooltip</Tooltip>
          </Pane>
        </Rectangle>
      </Pane>
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```

### [Working codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-pane-w5wgbs?file=/src/Map.js:121-777)

Comment: Thanks Seth, I have a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71756259/react-leaflet-tooltips-are-hidden-behind-other-layer-despite-higher-z-index. Could you have a look please?