# React-Leaflet Tooltips are hidden behind other layer despite higher z-index

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet

That is a follow-up question on [React-Leaflet How to show tooltips above layer when using panes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71721349/react-leaflet-how-to-show-tooltips-above-layer-when-using-panes/71727484#71727484).

When I add a circle, the tooltip of the rectangle is hidden behind the circle, even though the z-Index of the tooltip is higher. This is confusing me, why does this happen?

```
const Map = (props) => {
  return (
    <MapContainer center={[48, 11]} zoom={8} id="mapId">
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <Pane name="rectanglePane" style={{ zIndex: 401 }}>
        <Rectangle
          bounds={[
            [47.5, 10.5],
            [48.5, 11.5]
          ]}
        >
          <Pane name="ttPane" style={{ zIndex: 403 }}>
            <Tooltip sticky>Rectangle Tooltip</Tooltip>
          </Pane>
        </Rectangle>
      </Pane>
      <Pane name="circlePane" style={{ zIndex: 402 }}>
        <Circle
          center={[48, 11]}
          radius={20000}
        >
          <Pane name="ttCirclePane" style={{ zIndex: 404 }}>
            <Tooltip sticky>Circle Tooltip</Tooltip>
          </Pane>
        </Circle>
      </Pane>
    </MapContainer>
  );
};
```

[image: Map]

Comment: In your code example, does the ```name="ttCirclePane"``` element appear behind ```name="rectanglePane"```?

Comment: No, but the `ttPane` is behind the `circlePane`, which I do not want. I have added an image showing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is caused by the fact that a child element's `z-index` is limited by the parent element's `z-index`. So because `<Pane name="rectanglePane" style={{ zIndex: 401 }}>` has a lower `z-index` than `<Pane name="circlePane" style={{ zIndex: 402 }}>`, all elements inside `rectanglePane` will always appear behind `circlePane` no matter what their `z-index` is.

To get your application to work the way you want it, you will have to add the `ttPane` element inside another element that is outside of `<Pane name="rectanglePane" style={{ zIndex: 401 }}>` and one that has a higher `z-index` than `circlePane`. You will then have to work through the logistics of triggering that element which is out of the scope of this question.

I have noticed that you are likely using components imported from another library. If that is the case and you can't add the tooltip outside of the `rectanglePane` element, you can try to dynamically control the zIndexes inside state and switching their values between `rectanglePane` and `circlePane` (which will switch the circle/border appearance order) . This will also involve adding your own logic, but it is unfortunately the only other way of achieving your desired result.

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation! Let me explain the envisioned behaviour: I have a grid of rectangles on the map, each with a different tooltip. On top of some of the rectangles circles are shown. The circles needs to be clickable (the rectangles not). The tooltips should show on top. So, if I could give the rectangles a higher z-index than the circles, but have the circles still clickable it would work. I do not understand your last paragraph fully, what do you mean by components from another library? And dynamically switching zIndexes based on mouse position, or how?

Comment: 'give the rectangles a higher z-index than the circles, but have the circles still clickable' will not be straightforward. You will have to create an invisible circle which would have an event listener and trigger the circle behind the rectangle when clicked. When I say 'components from another library', I am questioning if you are the one who created those components or are they imported from another library, because if they are you will have more difficulty in doing the logic I mentioned. 'dynamically switching zIndexes based on mouse position,' means keeping zIndexes in react ```useState```

Comment: However the workaround to get your app to work the way you need it to is beyond the original question you have asked in this thread and you will have to create a new question to get more specific answers.